# wordpress - using ajax to submit form on post edit page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to understand basic ajax form submission in wordpress in order to submit a form from post edit page. Please excuse newbie posting but any help or pointers would be much appreciated as I'm lost here and many things I don't understand. I've tried a number of tutorials and examples but can't get them to work or adapt them to work. To do below I'm trying to adapt example at [Submitting a form with ajax in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777728/submitting-a-form-with-ajax-in-wordpress)

Basics -

1. add form to post edit page using plugin
2. submit form data via ajax
3. insert data into database with php handler

i don't want to submit data to post_meta table but to a custom table. required as there should be multiple form submissions, ie same form submitted many times from post edit page.

**1. add form to post edit page using plugin**

Plugin adds form to page (from example above)

```
<div class="inside">
<form class="form" id="ajax-contact-form" action="#">                            
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Name">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

But this form is nested within `<form name="post" action="post.php" method="post" id="post">`. I want the form to be separate from main `post` form so user will only submit `ajax-contact-form` data, not full post data. Is this a problem? My instinct says it is but I don't know solution

**2. submit form data via ajax**

Below (also adapted from example) is added in main plugin php and outputs ok to admin header but I'm not sure what `add_action` hook should be.

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'contact_form_javascript' );

function contact_form_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#ajax-contact-form').submit(function(e){
var name = $("#name").val();
$.ajax({ 
     data: {action: 'contact_form', name:name},
     type: 'post',
     url: ajaxurl,
     success: function(data) {
          alert(data); //should print out the name since you sent it along

    }
});

});
</script>
```

this does not seem to pass data to handler

**3. Insert data into database with php handler**

I've tested below works to insert ok by adapting example from http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins . But ajax data from javascript above does not seem to reach handler below.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_contact_form', 'contact_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_form', 'contact_form');

function contact_form()
{
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert( 
'ajaxtesttable', 
array( 
'col1' => $_POST["name"]
), 
array(
    '%s' 

) 
);

echo $wpdb->insert_id;
die();
}
```

I don't think problem is with handler, handler seems to be the easy bit. **I think issue is with either -**

**plugin form position on edit page OR javascript to 'ajax' data to php handler.**

I'm doing above as baby steps to sending full form data via ajax to handler. What I really want is the javascript that will send full form data to handler, by serialising it and passing it through. A simple example of how to do this would be great.

note: I've also tried to enqueue built in jquery form handler with below. This would seem simple way to submit data. But I don't see below reflected in source code

```
//to enqueue the built in jquery-form of Wordpress

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'inputtitle_submit_scripts' );
function inputtitle_submit_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-form'); // it should load /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.form.js
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'inputtitle_submit_scripts2' );
function inputtitle_submit_scripts2() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'json-form' ); // it should load /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.form.js
```

any help with above long question would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Part 1 is not clear, how you're doing that? And what's the goal of this form?

Comment: **Goal of form**

The scenario is evaluating training courses where students return feedback forms on their opinion of a course. So each taught course = a wp post , and a course may have many feedback forms returned for it.

So eg - 

course = 'Learn French'  (a wp post)
num feedback forms returned = 50 ('post meta' but wp post meta table not suitable)

means submitting 50 forms related to 'Learn French' . in this scenario an administrator, not the students, enter the form data so would be good to do on wp_admin side.

Comment: I tried 'advanced custom fields' plugin for this as it's repeater field seemed ideal, but this returns too many vars to server (eg 50 forms with 40 questions per form = 2000 db inserts) . Otherwise ACF plugin is very good. 

Given amount of data there can only be one feedback form submitted at any one time.

Comment: **Plugin**

plugin places form with `add_meta_box()` , there doesn't seem to be an option to place meta box outside the main post form, presently i have - `add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes', 20, 2 );`

see - http://www.wproots.com/complex-meta-boxes-in-wordpress/

maybe there's another function available to add form to admin post edit page but i cannot find one.

Answer (score 1):

I can spot one big problem in the code in the hook `admin_head`:

- it's lacking [jQuery noConflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)
- it's safer to print this in `admin_footer`
- it has to print only in the screen `post.php`
- it has to print only in the correct post type

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'contact_form_javascript' );

function contact_form_javascript() {
    if( 'post' != get_current_screen()->post_type )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    alert('Working only in the desired screen'); // Debug
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        // Now it's safe to use $
        // And the code will be available when safe: document.ready
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

And then, I'd try to avoid putting the `<form>` wrapper, as WP may get confused with its own `publish-post` form action.