# why WP Ajax data printed in the console instead of the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

this the first function of the Ajax call runs on focusout woocommerce input fields with `check_country_fees` action and url `'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'` **so how to pass the returned data and passing them as arguments normally?**

```
function addEvtListenerToCheckoutPage()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                document.getElementById('billing_first_name').addEventListener("focusout", function() {
                    alert("Hello World!");
                    if (document.getElementById('billing_first_name') !== "") {

                        var billing_first_name = document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value;
                        alert("testajax");
                        var data = {
                            action: 'check_country_fees',
                            billing_first_name: document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value
                        };

                        jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {
                            if (response.success == true) {
                                // Handle Success       
                                //  let resp = JSON.parse(response.data.json_response);
                                if (response.success) {
                                    alert(response);
                                    console.log(response);
                                    alert(response);
                                    alert("Sucess");
                                    // Hanle Success Response
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.log(response);
                                console.log(data);
                                alert("Sucess");
                            }
                        }).fail(function(response) {
                            // Handle Error
                            console.log("failing");

                            console.log(response);
                            alert("FAIl");

                        });

                    }

                });


            });
        });
        //     document.getElementById("#billing_first_name").addEventListener("input", myFunction);
    
    </script>
    <?php


    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
        alert("sended addevent");
    </script>
<?php

}
```

when I run the action call function `add_action('wp_ajax_check_country_fees', 'testing_ajax_action');` **the result printed in the browser console like that**

```
   </script>
        <script>
        alert("sended datasuccess");
    </script>
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    testing ajaaaaxnullArray
(
    [action] => check_country_fees
    [billing_first_name] => Stevea
)
Stevea</br>

    <script>
        alert("test ajaxbilling name");
    </script>
SteveaArray
(
)
```

Receiving data function

```
function testing_ajax_action()
{
    echo "testing ajaaaax";
    if (isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) {
        $billing_first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
        $billing_first_name = json_decode($billing_first_name);
       
        extract($_POST);

        print_r($_POST);
        $billing_first_name2 = json_decode($_POST['billing_first_name_post']);
        //testingajax($billing_first_name);
        testingajax($billing_first_name);
    } else {

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote `console.log(response);`. Why do expect that to make it appear in the page and not the console?

Comment: @Quentin I deleted this part but still the fucntion doesn't execute it's first time to know if in debug the result it won't be sent!, so that mean the action doesn't fire at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data back from the backend to the frontend.

Here is a crude basic diagram of an ajax request:

> Event `→` JS request `→` PHP Processing `→` PHP Response `→` JS Handling

If you're not sending any data with your PHP response then you can't handle it on the front end.

You can use [`wp_send_json_success()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/) and [`wp_send_json_error()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/) to send the appropriate response `success`/`error` status and attach to it any relevant data you want to handle on the front end.

By convention, the PHP Processing function [is usually anonymous](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

From a security standpoint you should implement a [nonce system](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) too. You can refer to the following answer about [using Ajax the right way in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70669262/3645650).

Coming back to your problem, you can pass an array through `wp_send_json_success`.

```php
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_{$action}', function () {

    if ( check_ajax_referer( '_ajax_nonce' ) ) {

        //...

        $data = array(
            'timestamp' => time(),
            'key' => 'value',
            //...
        );

        wp_send_json_success( $data );

    } else {
        
        wp_send_json_error();

    };

} );
```

On the javascript handling side, you would intercept it and do something with it:

```js
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: ( response ) => {
        console.log( response.data );
        //...
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: the issue that the action and the function not firing, and 'wp_ajax' depending on the users logged in or not can I use something  in general I also used this as a test and changed the ajax variable also still not firing `add_action('wp_ajax_{$action}', function () {
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("test ajaxbilling name");
    </script>
    <?php`

Comment: but the ajax call reponse is sucessful

Comment: I think you have a fundamental lack of understanding on how the ajax "system" works, you should take the time to read https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.

Comment: You can use `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` for non-logged-in users. @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/.

Comment: Your ajax request isn't standard, you're not defining an action. You're not defining a nonce. Read the documentation first before trying to make it work on the go, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: My point of view is when the php function called with the action also it goes into the console log not on the server side.

Comment: this alert message printed in the console 

`function    check_country_fees()
{
    echo "testing callback";
?>
    <script>
        alert("test ajaxbilling name check country");
    </script>
<?php  
}` and `add_action('wp_ajax_check_country_fees', 'check_country_fees');`